# Incorrect output for UTF8 conversion using iconv

Tags: c++, utf-8, iconv

I am trying to convert string encoded in **ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 on Linux**. I am using **iconv** function to do that in C++. This is the code that I have:

```
//Conversion from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8
iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1");

char *input = "€"; // the byte value is 128 in ISO-8859-1
char *inputbuf= input;
size_t inputSize=1;

char *output = (char*)malloc(inputSize*4); // maximum size of a character in UTF8 is 4
char *outputbuf = output;
size_t outputSize = inputSize*4;

//Conversion Function
iconv (cd, &inputbuf, &inputSize, &outputbuf, &outputSize);

//Display input bytes(ISO-8859-1)
cout << "input bytes(ISO-8859-1):"
for (int i=0; i<inputSize; i++)
{
    cout <<(int) *(input+i) << ", ";
}
cout<< std::endl;

//Display Converted bytes(UTF-8)
cout << "output bytes(UTF-8):"
for (int i=0; i<outputSize; i++) //displaying all the 4 bytes allocated
{
    cout <<(int) *(output+i) << ", ";
}
cout<< std::endl;
iconv(cd);
```

This is the output I observe:

```
input bytes(ISO-8859-1): 128
output bytes(UTF-8): 194, 128, 0, 0
```

As you can see, the output UTF-8 converted bytesis 194,128. However, the expected UTF-8 output is 226,130,172. I verified that there is no error thrown by any of the iconv functions.

Can anyone please help me figure out if I am missing anything here?

Comment: According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), the code 128 is _undefined_ in the ISO 8859-1 code page.

Comment: `€` is NOT byte 128 (0x80) in ISO-8859-1.  In fact, byte 0x80 is unassigned in ISO-8859-1.  You are thinking of [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (or other similar charset), which does have `€` in byte 0x80 (it is not always 0x80 in all supporting charsets, though).  Windows-1252 is commonly mistaken for ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @YSC: [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) encodes `€` as byte 164 (0xA4).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the utfcpp library: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/ or Boost.Locale for that purpose

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug of iconv, as `0xc2 0x80` is a valid utf-8 sequence for the [code point `U+0080` glyph *<control>*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm).

This glyph is often mistaken for the [glyph *EURO SIGN*, code point `U+20AC`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20aC/index.htm) encoded as `0xe2 0x82 0xac` in UTF-8.

Comment: Well, the more I thing of it the more I question my conclusion... does ISO-8859-1 have an EURO SIGN glyph? ISO-8859-15 sure does, but...

Comment: The difference between ISO-8859-1 ("Latin-1") and ISO-8859-15 ("Latin-9") is that the latter has the € sign, which is missing from the former. So it's not a bug in iconv, I'd say.

Comment: No, ISO-8859-1 does not have the EURO symbol.  ISO-8859-15 and Windows-1252 are off-shoots of ISO-8859-1 that add the EURO (amongst others).

Comment: @lenz Thank you guys. I keep my answer anyway, still a bug of iconv.

Comment: @YSC: [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) encodes `€` as 0xA4, not 0x80